# which place is more suitable for fetch in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 2 screens; one displays user info, and the other allows user info to be edited.

In the first screen in `componentDidMount` I make a fetch request to the db to check if there is information about user. If not, the user has to move to the second screen and fill in some inputs. In that case, where the user moved from first screen to the second and back to the first, `componentDidMount` will not be triggered for the second time and I will not receive actual data; how should I remedy this?

Comment: please, add code samples/[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise, it is not clear why navigation from screen #2 to screen #1 is not triggering latter's `cDM`

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to have the code in `componentDidMount`? There are other ways of triggering events.